# Compare Acronym Field to Init Caps Field

Tags: mysql

I have a table with Name|Acronym but want to confirm they are all 'correct'; in other words Certified Public Accountant = CPA. I there a way to make sure that the initials of the acronym match the initials of the first letter of each word in the term field?

Answer (score 0):

As there is no split function in sql as far as i know, you will have to create one with substring functions so you would better do this verification in your code with the language your using

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you have a maximum number of words in the list.  The following query returns errors in the first three letters:

```
select w.*
from words w
where (length(w.acronym) >= 1 and left(w.words, 1) <> left(w.acronym, 1)) and
      (length(w.acronym) >= 2 and left(substring_index(substring_index(w.words, ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 1) <> substring(w.acronym, 2, 1)) and
      (length(w.acronym) >= 3 and left(substring_index(substring_index(w.words, ' ', 3), ' ', -1), 1) <> substring(w.acronym, 3, 1))
```

You can continue the logic up to the maximum length of the acronyms.